# Rails Console find users by array of ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-console

So I have an array of user ids. Is there a way in rails console to query all of these user's with the array

something like

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

users = User.find(ids)
```

and have it return all 4 users?

Comment: It does work. You can pass an array of IDs to the model's find method and, provided they are all existing IDs, you will get back an array of user's for those IDs.

Comment: Didn't realized this worked... haha. Should have tested it.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

For an array, you can use one of these:

```
# Will raise exception if any value not found
User.find( [1,3,5] )

# Will not raise an exception
User.find_all_by_id( [1,3,5] ) # Rails 3
User.where(id: [1,3,5])        # Rails 4
```

If you happen to be using a range, you can use these:

```
# Will raise exception if any value not found
User.find((1..4).to_a)   #same as User.find([1,2,3,4])

# Will not raise an exception
User.find_all_by_id(1..4)  # Rails 3
User.where(id: 1..4)       # Rails 4
```

As @diego.greyrobot notes in a comment, a range causes a SQL BETWEEN clause, whereas an array causes a SQL IN clause.

*Don't* use `User.find_by_id()` -- It will only return one record, no matter how may IDs you pass in.

Comment: My actual array isn't from 1 - 4. The ids are sporadic for example 122, 323, 451. Can I still achieve that?

Comment: There's a few inaccuracies here: User.find((1..4).to_a) will make it work. And: 1..4 creates a Range not an Array.

Comment: Yes, it's important to note that passing in a range (User.find_all_by_id(1..4)) will execute a sql BETWEEN clause, whereas passing in an array will do a sql IN statement.

Comment: Edited to add Rails 4 preferred versions.

Comment: Note: Duplication and order will be ignored. I use a hash to preserve both: `ids = [3, 3, 1, 0, 3]; Model.find(ids).map(:id) == [0, 1, 3]; h = Model.find(ids.uniq).map{|o| [o.id, o]}.to_h; h.values_at(ids).map(:id) == [3, 3, 1, 0, 3]`

Comment: Does `find` vs `where` result in the same sql query?

Comment: .find returns `Array`. Whereas .where returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Answer (score 17):

you can use `User.where(id: ids)`

Comment: In Rails 4, `find_all_by_id` is deprecated, so use `where`.

Comment: And in rails 5, it appears not to work at all, so definitely use ```User.where(id: [1,2,3,4])```

Answer (score 4):

Use splash operator:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

users = User.find(*ids)
```

Note that it will raise an exception if it fails to find any of the users.

Comment: Ooh, that's neat.  I didn't know about that one.

Comment: You don't need to splat it, find takes an array just fine.

Comment: I'm finding that too.  The splat does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

This is work for me...

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

users = User.find(ids)

users = User.find(*ids)

users = User.find_all_by_id(ids)
```

All are working..

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is supposed to work when all the ids exist.

The reason you might be seeing an exception is because at least one of those ids does not exist in the database.

Instead, you want to use `find_all_by_id` if you don't want to get an exception:

```
User.find_all_by_id([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Does the following sql:    
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
   Users.where({ id: [1,2,3 ,4]})
 # SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I would encourage you to expand on this answer to provide some explanation. An answer that is all code doesn't really provide a lot of information to other users that are unfamiliar with the concepts in the question.