# Get all Rails records from an array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have an array of record IDs `["303", "430", "4321", "5102"]`. I want to get all records that match these IDs, using SQL:

```
acceptable_ids = ["303", "430", "4321", "5102"]
@users = User.where("is_awesome = true AND id IN acceptable_ids)
```

Gives this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
```

What is the correct way to write my query to get all users with ids that match `acceptable_ids`?

*Note:*

I am aware of `User.find(acceptable_ids)`, but can't use this since I am constructing a SQL query with select, where, and join clauses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Console find users by array of ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435768/rails-console-find-users-by-array-of-ids)

Comment: @BradWerth please read the note at the bottom of my question, thanks :)

Comment: I guess this isn't your actual code because it has syntax errors in it...

Comment: Your where statement is missing the closing double quote.

Comment: I saw your note, did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21436165/525478  or http://stackoverflow.com/a/21435842/525478 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/25983580/525478 , all of which use where... That is one of the reasons I picked that question, out of the dozen or so on the site...

Comment: It is covered in the docs for where, also, for future reference. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could do this.

```
@users = User.where("is_awesome = true AND id IN (#{acceptable_ids.join(', ')})")
```

I'm sure I've seen a simpler way but can't recall it at the moment... but above should work.

EDIT

However, you can see from the vociferous comments that this is not a popular answer, so you should look at some of the alternatives linked and listed, e.g.

```
# Will raise exception if any value not found
User.find( [1,3,5] )

# Will not raise an exception
User.find_all_by_id( [1,3,5] )
```

Comment: Argument conversion should certainly be handed over to ActiveRecord. Doing otherwise is bad practice as it makes SQL injections more probable, especially with beginners.

Comment: I think you have an extra parenthesis in there right?

Comment: Thanks @DonnyP ... I think I was missing a closing parenthesis, just added it.

Comment: This answer is so bad I have to down vote it. Please look at the other answer to see how it should be done. You should never concatenate SQL queries by hand (possible SQL injection), and you should use what Rails gives you instead of reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Thanks, @MichalSzyndel, always happy to improve. :)

Comment: You're definitely opening yourself up to SQL injection here.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions you could fix this answer like `@users = User.where("is_awesome = true AND id IN ?",acceptable_ids.join(', '))`, but it would still not be as good as http://stackoverflow.com/a/25982790/525478 (or 3 of the answers in the question linked as a dupe)

Answer (score 11):

```
User.where(is_awesome: true, id: acceptable_ids)
```