# Get documents by querying over an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have an array of ids. Now I want to get all the documents corresponding to the ids inside that array from a collection.
Is there any command by which I can achieve this?

I don't want to run a loop over that array and query for every element of the array.

Assume the array is

```
id = [1,2,3,4]
```

The collection is Scores, which has the field `id` among other fields.
I'm looking for something like `Scores.find(..)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Console find users by array of ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435768/rails-console-find-users-by-array-of-ids)

Comment: you can pass in an array of ids in the `find` method and it will return all the results

Comment: Yes that's the one, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord, the following query works as expected

```
Scores.find([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Depending on the MongoDB adapter you use, it may work as well. According to [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#queries-persistence), the same syntax is also supported in Mongoid.

Otherwise, you can generally use

```
Scores.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

that will return a collection of records matching the given IDs.